# How can I replace all rows containing alphabets with spaces in a column in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date-time column which contains date time in this format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'

The same column also contains some junk alphabet values such as 'Expiration date' and 'date of the day'

I want to replace all the rows containing alphabets such as 'Expiration date' and 'date of the day'
with blank spaces except the rows containing date time in this format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'

I am not able to figure out a way to do that, Is there any regex I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`try_to_date()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html):

```
select try_to_date(col, MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

This returns `NULL`, which seems more useful than a bunch of spaces.  But you could convert to spaces using `COALESCE()`:

```
select coalesce(try_to_date(col, MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), '                ')
```